# SED not splitting getting substring I want

Tags: regex, bash, sed, solaris

I am hashing a file with Message Authentication Code, then I need to encode the file hash in base64. To do that I am using OpenSSL as below:

```
#Create HMAC-SHA2 hash from file
filehash=`mac -a sha256_hmac -k private.key $filename`
##base64 encode filehash
filehash_64=`echo "$filehash" | /usr/sfw/bin//openssl enc -base64 | sed 's/^.*= //'`
```

The problem is that OpenSSL outputs the original hash and the encoded hash, so I am using SED to split the string and get the encoded part. However when I test this out it is not splitting.

Encoded filehash

```
YmUzMjA1NzE2MzIyZDYwZWN  YTU5MmRiMGUxYWVjZTk3OQo=
```

All I want is this:

```
YTU5MmRiMGUxYWVjZTk3OQo=
```

Have I missed something in the SED code, or is my piping wrong?

```
sed 's/^.*= //'`
```

Comment: is both are two separate lines?

Comment: Nope they are on the same output line for some reason the formatting on here has put them on two lines

Comment: See my edit, both string are seperated by whitepace

Comment: You are matching a `=` before the space, but it's not there, that's the problem.

Comment: Can you give me the new regex @LevLevitsky

Comment: I had in mind something like @AvinashRaj shows. The `^` is not needed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this sed command.

```
sed 's/^.* //'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'YmUzMjA1NzE2MzIyZDYwZWN  YTU5MmRiMGUxYWVjZTk3OQo=' | sed 's/^.* //'
YTU5MmRiMGUxYWVjZTk3OQo=
```

Comment: Solaris requires backticks , please be aware!

Comment: did you try this ? ``echo "$filehash" | /usr/sfw/bin//openssl enc -base64 | sed 's/^.* //'``

Answer (score 0):

This awk command should work

```
awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Prints the second column, its really basic.